# How to import Protocol Buffer as module in Android.mk?

Tags: android, android-ndk, protocol-buffers, ndk-build

I tried call the `protobuf` as an Android module, first I configure the variable `NDK_MODULE_PATH` with the modules project folder and in the `Android.mk` I call $`(call import-module, protobuf)` like that:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

$(call import-module, protobuf)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#...
```

But it gives me an error:

```
Android NDK: Trying to define local module 'protobuf-cpp-lite' in /home/alex/Projects/network-simulator/3rd-party/protobuf/Android.mk.    
Android NDK: But this module was already defined by /home/alex/Projects/network-simulator/3rd-party/protobuf/Android.mk.    
/opt/android-ndk-r10/build/core/build-module.mk:34: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
```

When I tried to build `protobuf` separately in its folder I got the same error.